# How to call codeigniter application inside cms?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, content-management-system

Is it possible to have a codeigniter application running inside a cms?

I'm putting together a website where somebody else is making all the menus and content except for one. For this one menu I want to run a codeigniter application but I want to keep the design of the cms.

I hope it makes sense.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it works like that, especially with Wordpress. I would assume you would need to modify CodeIgniter pretty heavily in order for it to make it work like that.

I would suggest PyroCMS, which is a CMS built on CodeIgniter. You will be able to find it easier to modify than hacking CodeIgniter to make it work on Wordpress.

PyroCMS is just as easy as Wordpress, so I don't think there won't be much learning curve.

http://www.pyrocms.com/

Comment: I am not familiar with pyroCMS, but I really like all the themes you can find for wordpress. I am programmer more than I am a webdesigner. So what are my options regarding themes?

Comment: @user1134132: They have a templating system but there prebuilt themes are lacking. Pyro is young and has only just release 2.0. But its a solid CMS system with a dedicated community and development staff.

Comment: @user1134132 You can easily go through any wordpress theme, and tune it up to work with pyroCMS. I suggest you give it a shot first

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to keep the design you don't need to run Codeigniter inside wordpress.

Take the output of the wordpress template that you like (or template files really) and use that as your starting point with any views you write in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score -1):

Check out fuelcms http://getfuelcms.com. It's a CMS built on codeigniter as well.